# Hiding constructor

Tags: haskell, module

I'm a beginner in Haskell.
Let's say Rat is the type of fractions of integeres or an integer. I'd like to ask, why does export this the Rat's constructors?

```
module RatNum(Rat,add1Rat,makeRat) where
    infixl 5 :/
    data Rat = Int :/ Int | Only Int deriving(Show)
    add1Rat :: Rat -> Rat
    add1Rat (a :/ b) = (a+b) :/ b
    add1Rat (Only a) = Only (a+1)
    makeRat :: Rat
    makeRat = 1 :/ 1
    makeORat :: Rat
    makeORat = Only 1
```

In GHCI:

```
Prelude> :l RatNum
[1 of 1] Compiling RatNum           ( RatNum.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: RatNum.
*RatNum> Only 5
Only 5
*RatNum> add1Rat (1:/3)
4 :/ 3
*RatNum> 7:/5
7 :/ 5
```

The module is not finished yet and I'd like to hide the constructors of Rat.

Comment: For the record, what you're doing is available in the [`Data.Ratio`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Ratio.html) module already.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's because you're loading the module itself from ghci. Try out this code, in a file `Main.hs` in the same directory as `RatNum.hs`:

```
module Main where

import RatNum

f = Only 1
```

Now try to load `Main` from ghci:

```
$ ghci Main.hs
GHCi, version 7.0.4: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
[1 of 2] Compiling RatNum           ( RatNum.hs, interpreted )
[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, interpreted )

Main.hs:5:5: Not in scope: data constructor `Only'
Failed, modules loaded: RatNum.
```

**EXPLANATION**

Have a look at [this ghci manual page](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#id3045728), section 2.4.5. It explains that every module GHCI puts into your command prompt *is currently in scope; the visible identifiers are exactly those that would be visible in a Haskell source file with no import declaration (cite)*.

Your command prompt says `RatNum` because you told ghci to load it, so the prompt works in the same scope as within that module.
In my example it was only referenced by the module I actually loaded, `Main`, thus I did not enter in the scope of `RatNum`.

When you will actually compile (or reference through `import`s) your code, the export declarations will work as you expect.

Comment: This fails to load Main.hs and loads RatNum and the constructors are there again. Or am I missing something? And what's this error about?

Comment: I mean this error
    Main.hs:5:5: Not in scope: data constructor `Only'

Comment: That's the point. It fails because, as you would expect, you cannot access the constructor from outside your module.

Comment: I am sorry, I see now. Thank you for the answer, do i have to make this thread solved or sg?

Comment: If I fully answered to your question, then you should mark my answer as accepted by clicking on the "v" sign. Thanks :)